# C# Xamarin UITest- how to assert that both an element exists and text is correct

Tags: c#, xamarin, ui-testing

Scenario:

While writing automated tests in C# (i.e. Xamarin UITest, Nunit, etc), I want to assert both that an element is present and that the text of that element is correct. (i.e. the element X exist and the text seen is Y)

Intellisense tells me that Assert is an option, but I can't seem to figure out the recipe to accomplish this.

I can do something like "app.Flash(e => e.Id("TheId"));" , which would show the human user the element flashing, but I want to actually assert that it's there, with the correct text presented to the user.

Answer (score 4):

Here is an example of waiting for a page to appear, testing if some element is available and then testing the the element contains a certain value.

#### Single Asset Test case

```
[Test]
public void StackOverEntry()
{
    // Wait for the page to appear, test to see if some static (always present) element is available
    AppResult[] results = app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"));

    var elementQuery = app.Query(c => c.Marked("SOEntry"));
    var elementAvailable = elementQuery.Any();
    string elementValue = "";
    if (elementAvailable)
        elementValue = elementQuery.First().Text;

    Assert.IsTrue(elementAvailable && elementValue == "StackOverflow", "Not available and/or correct");
}
```

#### Individual Asserts Test case

```
[Test]
public void StackOverEntry()
{
    // Wait for the page to appear, test to see if some static (always present) element is available
    AppResult[] results = app.WaitForElement(c => c.Marked("Welcome to Xamarin Forms!"));
    // Test of the element is on the page (via AutomationId in this class)
    Assert.NotNull(app.Query(c => c.Marked("SOEntry")).FirstOrDefault());
    // Test the the element contains the proper value
    Assert.AreEqual("StackOverflow", app.Query(c => c.Marked("SOEntry")).First().Text);
}
```

#### XAML being tested:

```
<StackLayout Orientation="Vertical">
    <Label Text="Welcome to Xamarin Forms!" VerticalOptions="Center" HorizontalOptions="Center" />
    <Entry AutomationId="SOEntry" Text="StackOverflow" />        
</StackLayout>
```